# SQL Server stored procedure being deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is being delete while clients are using the system, and they don't have access to the database. So they could not delete it manually

I saw a lot of people saying that it could be a missing `GO` before `IF EXISTS... DROP PROC` statement, but this procedure is not disappearing at the moment we run the script to update the database, it is being deleted while the users are using the system.

There is no `DROP` at the C# code. So I don't have idea what is going on. 
What could be dropping it?

Comment: Do you have any level of mirroring or replication setup?

Comment: No, I don't. I can only think that some type of C# exception is doing it

Comment: You should query default trace running on SQL server to see who is dropping it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the people saying that a "GO" was missing meant that the `IF EXISTS DROP` is now embedded inside some stored procedure. This would explain why it disappears when people are using the system and not when you run the update script (since the `IF EXISTS DROP` is part of a proc definition and not immediately runnable).  Run the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [definition] LIKE N'%DROP_%PROC%';
-- Use _% between the words to account for whitespace variations but still require
-- at least one character
```

in that database to see if anything shows up.

To explain what has happened, your script looks like the following:

```sql
// a bunch of SQL statements

GO
IF EXISTS(...SomeProc1)
   DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc1;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc1
AS
 ....

// oops, no GO here

IF EXISTS(...SomeProc2)
   DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc2;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc2
AS
 ....

GO
```

Because there is no "GO" between the `CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc1` and the `IF EXISTS(...SomeProc2)`, the `IF EXISTS(...SomeProc2)` is now part of `SomeProc1` (at the end of it). Each time `SomeProc1` runs, it will drop `SomeProc2`.

---

You can also check the script that did the database updates, look for the definition of the proc that is being dropped, and look just above it to see what code it became a part of.

---

You should also check your SQL Agent jobs to make sure that there isn't a step that has an embedded DROP:

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE [command] LIKE N'%DROP_%PROC%';
```

Comment: Your SELECT didn't return any row. I have a trigger that catches all the DDL that were executed, and it got only this strange DROP that was executed by SA

Comment: @Mucida Did you run the SELECT while in the database that the proc is disappearing from? You can also check the script that did the database updates, look for the definition of the proc that is being dropped, and look just above it to see what code it became a part of. Also, whitespace might affect the search results so I will update my answer with a new search string.

Comment: Yes, I did. The most strang thing is that after we recreate the procedure, the clients can use the system normally, but after using the same process reaetedily all day, this procedure is droped again,"randomly". That is why I guess that a C# exception is doing it

Comment: @Mucida I don't see how an exception is dropping a proc unless you put code to do a SqlCommand running a DROP inside of a catch block. I also would hope that your app is not logging into the database as "sa" or an account that is a member of the "sysadmin" role. That would be bad. I will put 2 other ideas in my answer in just a moment.

Comment: I found the DROP PROC.. Somebody did some update in the database, that is why I didn't see it at first time. I got the backup and found a procedure1 with drop procedure2 at the end

Comment: and i used all_sql_modules

Comment: @Mucida Great! But are you saying that you didn't catch it at first due to someone updating the proc that had the DROP statement in it so technically the problem was already fixed? Also, `all_sql_modules` _shouldn't_ have been necessary as it also includes the system objects and I doubt someone updated one of those.

Comment: I think that the last database update, somebody deleted the extra DROP statement from the wrong procedure, that is why I didn't found it. In a previous version I found the DROP

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a DDL trigger for DROP_PROCEDURE

Then you can prevent the drop unless the system admin does it. Or you can record when it was dropped and by who so you can research what is happening.